# Why Godel have chosen $\omega$-consistency of a theory instead of it proving it's own consistency?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness

Godel assumed $\omega$-consistency for his proof of the first incompleteness theorem to run. But, isn't it the case that if we assume that a theory $T$ is effective, complete and $\omega$-consistent, then this would entail that $ T \vdash \operatorname {Con}(T)$? On the other hand, if we assume that $T$ is effective, complete, and proves its own consistency; then would this necessarily entail that $T$ is $\omega$-consistent? If NO, then demanding $ T\vdash \operatorname{ Con}(T)$ would be a weaker assumption that does the job! So, it can prove incompleteness even for some theories that are not $\omega$-consistent. By then, the question would be why Godel chose $\omega$-consistency, while he could have chosen a weaker obvious assumption. If YES, then $\omega$-consistency would be a simpler statement. So, which case is true?

---

Based on comments by @spaceisdarkgreen it would be more reasonable to ask about replacing the $\omega$-consistency assumption by the condition of $T \not \vdash \neg \operatorname{Con}(T)$, i.e., the theory not proving its own inconsistency.

So, Godel's incompleteness would be presented as:"every effective (represents all computable functions) theory that doesn't prove its own inconsistency, is incomplete".

This will cover all effective $\omega$-consistent theories, and as well would add **other** theories on the table! For example, an arithmetically sound but $\omega$-inconsistent theory.

The whole setting of this question is about assumptions for the original Godel proof to run. And, so it is not about Rosser's improvements. So, here, I'm arguing that $T \not \vdash \neg \operatorname {Con}(T)$ might constitute a better alternative to $\omega$-consistency, for that particular purpose.

Comment: He was unable to find the proof under the simple consistency assumption. See [Rosser's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick).

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1308307/why-is-omega-consistency-needed-in-g%c3%b6dels-original-incompleteness-proof).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I'm not speaking about the simple consistency assumption (which is meta-theoretic). No, I'm speaking about assuming $T \vdash \operatorname{Con}(T)$, this is different. This, straightforwardly establishes the proof, and there can be no weaker grounds.

Comment: But 2nd GIT says: $T \nvdash \text {Con}(T)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, Yes, this is a stronger result, it proves it even when $T$ is incomplete, it proves it once $T$ is effective and consistent. But, I'm speaking of the first incompleteness theorem. I mean instead of demanding that $T$ is $\omega$-consistent, he could have demanded that $T \vdash \operatorname{Con}(T)$. A simple straightforward assumption. No, need for $\omega$-consistency.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, I mean he could have said that: no consistent effective theory can be complete and at the same time proves its own consistency. That would have been simpler.

Comment: Sorry, not clear for me... My last comment is about the original G's proof has several step: the final one is based on the construction of a formula $G$ of $T$ and then the author proves: (i) that $T \nvdash G$ (and this step needs only the consistency of $T$), and (ii) that $T \nvdash \lnot G$ (and this step needs - in the original proof - the $\omega$-cons of $T$).

Comment: Why would $\omega$-consistency imply $T\vdash Con(T)$ (other than the obvious fact that all these assumptions together will imply $T$ is inconsistent, which I assume would defeat the purpose)? $\omega$-consistency is about what you *can't* prove, not what you *can* prove.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, Let $\phi(n,a,b)$ be the formula: $$\operatorname{Proof}_T(a,n) \uparrow \operatorname{Proof}_T(b, \operatorname{neg}(n))$$. Now, $\phi(n,a,b)$ is true for every substitution of $n,a,b$ by concrete naturals. Then, by $\omega$-consistency, we get: $$ T \not \vdash \exists n \exists a \exists b: \neg \phi(n,a,b)$$, and so by completeness, we'd have $$T \vdash \forall n \forall a \forall b: \phi(n,a,b)$$, but the sentence $``\forall n \forall a \forall b: \phi(n,a,b)"$ is itself $\operatorname{Con}(T)$.

Comment: @Zuhair Yes, certainly true in the presence of completeness (which is to say, $\omega$-consistency implies the theory *doesn't* prove its own *in*sconsistency), but then I guess I missed your point.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, my point was that Godel didn't need to add $\omega$-consistency of $T$ as an assumption, he could have instead just added that $T \vdash \operatorname{Con}(T)$, and that would sufficient for his proof to run. Not only that, it might be the case that $T \vdash \operatorname{Con}(T)$ doesn't imply $\omega$-consistency even in the presence of completeness and effectiveness of $T$. If that is correct, then Godel have made a strong assumption.

Comment: @Zuhair You're saying to replace an assumption that holds in most cases of interest with one that almost never holds in any cases of interest. I would say $T\vdash Con(T)$ is the "strong" assumption.

Comment: @Zuhair it would be helpful to clarify what you mean by “the proof going through”… what’s the theorem statement?

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, I'm speaking specifically in the context of proving the first incompleteness theorem, in that setting we are assuming $T$ to be consistent, effective and complete, but now we need to add some other criterion about $T$ to make the proof go through (i.e. prove the incompleteness result that there is a sentence in the language of $T$ that $T$ neither prove nor disprove). Now, this additional criterion was that $T$ is $\omega$-consistent. I'm arguing that instead we to add $T \vdash Con(T)$ becos it is just enough for that purpose.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, to be noted that I'm not speaking about Rosser's proof, or any similar proof that can actually prove the incompleteness result without requiring an additional criterion. I'm speaking specifically about Godel's proof, where this additional criterion of $\omega$-consistency was done. I see that it was simpler to just require $T$ to prove its own consistency. Since, that may (I'm not sure) even be a weaker condition, and if it turns to be strictly weaker than $\omega$-consistency, then Godel would have made a relatively unnecessary strong assumption.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, about what I mean by "strong" is that in the context of proving the first incompleteness result, every theory that is $\omega$-consistent would be a theory that proves its own consistency, but the converse may not hold, i.e. there may be theories that are consistent, effective, complete and prove their own consistency but yet are not $\omega$-consistent. In this setting the assumption of $\omega$-consistency would be unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: @Zuhair Here's where I'm confused: why are you assuming completeness in order to prove incompleteness? Godel's 1st incompleteness theorem is that if a theory is $\omega$-consistent, effective, and "interprets enough arithmetic", then it is incomplete. The "interprets.." condition can be made precise as $\Sigma_0$-completeness, but it's unusual to put (full) completeness as a hypothesis...  of course it's admissible since we're trying to prove the opposite, but we don't really want a proof by contradiction here, we want an actual sentence that is undecidable in actual consistent theories.

Comment: @Zuhair Something along the same lines that would make more sense to me would be to ask whether we can replace the $\omega$-consistency condition with $T\nvdash\lnot Con(T)$ and (easily) recover the proof. (Of course it suffices formally since it implies ordinary consistency, but similar to your question the point is to not make use of Rosser's improvement.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, I like this last suggestion of yours. I do also agree that it makes more sense, especially if we want to present proofs that are not by negation style proofs. Since, those would cover every actual $\omega$-consistent theory, and I think more. About why I demanded full completeness is because I was thinking a proof by negation. But, the point raised in connection to that is clear. Still, I think this $T \not \vdash Con(T)$ is better than $\omega$-consistency, since it may have wider coverage, i.e. proves a wider range of theories to be incomplete than with using $\omega$-con.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, actually $ T \not \vdash Con(T)$ even if it turns not to have wider coverage than $\omega$-consistency, and so be of equal strength. To me, it is an easier statement to make, and more into the essence of incompleteness proof that the indirect $\omega$-consistency assumption.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, sorry for the late response. I didn't see your last comment. Yes, what I'm saying is that the second step which $\omega$-consistency  was assumed for, (i.e. to prove $T \not \vdash \neg G$), it doesn't really need the strength of $\omega$-consistency. All what it needs is $T \not \vdash \neg \operatorname {Con}(T)$, that's all.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, I came to know that Isaacson had proved the result of $T \not \vdash \neg Con(T)$. He spells it as a theory being consistent with it's own consistency statement, which is the same. See: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-007-0214-1_7

Comment: Maybe useful the following research: Makoto Kikuchi and Kazuyuki Tanaka, [On Formalization of Model-Theoretic Proofs of Gödel's Theorems (NDJFL, 1994)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/notre-dame-journal-of-formal-logic/volume-35/issue-3/On-Formalization-of-Model-Theoretic-Proofs-of-G%c3%b6dels-Theorems/10.1305/ndjfl/1040511346.full), page 411: If PA + Con(PA) is consistent, then PA is incomplete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're forgetting the historical context of the theorem.

Prior to Godel's work, there is no reason to expect "$T\not\vdash\neg Con(T)$" to even make sense. By contrast, $\omega$-consistency makes perfect sense for a theory treating natural numbers. So as a hypothesis, even though it is stronger mathematically it is weaker *pedagogically* in the sense that it takes much less thought to motivate it. "Every [...] $\omega$-consistent theory is incomplete" is much more easily communicable, to a circa-$1931$ audience, than "Every [...] theory not proving its own inconsistency is incomplete."

*If* Godel numbering had been introduced significantly prior to the proof of the first incompleteness theorem, then "$T\not\vdash\neg Con(T)$" might have made sense as a hypothesis. But that's not what happened.

Comment: Ok, I understand the history point. But, my question is not just historical. Truly it's about Godel's original proof but it is not confined to the historical sense. It's about assumptions to make the proof run with a better coverage. Of course, without resorting to Rosser's or the alike.

Comment: about history point. Was $\omega$-consistency known before Godel? The concept of proof and inconsistency were certainly known before Godel's work. Though, I'm not sure, but I think even back then $T \not\vdash \neg Con(T)$ would be clearly understood. So, why add a new invention? Especially if the already understood statement is more directly related to the proof itself, and has wider coverage?

Comment: @Zuhair How would "$T\not\vdash\neg Con(T)$" be understood prior to Godel showing how $Con(T)$ could even be expressed in the language of $T$ in the first place? As the history of $\omega$-consistency, I'm not sure, but it doesn't take any substantive work to define.

Comment: Ok, then. He showed that. Then he could have easily presented it. Since, it is straightforwardly related to his proof in the first place.  Actually showing that consistency can be captured internally is by far much more important than presenting a new concept of consistency altogether. He should have pressed it further. So, there must have been something else on his mind. Anyhow, my point is still not about just history, even nowadays the presentation of Godel's proof makes connection to $\omega$-consistency as if it is necessary for his proof. It is not! In fact, it is restrictive!