$\omega$-consistency in Goedel's completeness
To prove $PA\not\vdash \lnot \Delta$, where $\Delta$ is the Goedel's sentence, satisfying:
$$PA\vdash \Delta\leftrightarrow \lnot Prv(\overline{\Delta})$$
Why cannot we say: If $PA\vdash \lnot \Delta$, then $PA\vDash \lnot \Delta$ by Goedel's completeness. As $\Bbb N$ is a model of PA, we have $\Bbb N\vDash \lnot\Delta$, so $\Bbb N\vDash Prv(\overline{\Delta})$, so there exists a natural number that encodes a proof of $\Delta$, and therefore $PA\vdash\Delta$, contradiction?
If so, then we do not need $\omega$-consistency but only need consistency. I had not thought about this before and am confused now. It must be my stupid. What is the error in the above argument?
Any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!

see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1308307

@RyanTay I did see this post. But may I please ask how to interpret that answer so it directly addresses my question? I am sorry that I do not see the relevance and I am afraid that I do need some help to reinterpret it to address myy question.

Yes, since $\mathbb N\models\sf PA$, $\sf PA$ is $\omega$-consistent and Gödel’s original proof applies to it. (And the completeness theorem is a red herring… you are just using the easy direction.) I don’t understand how you conclude “we only need consistency”. You are using $\mathbb N\models\sf PA$ which is full arithmetical soundness of $\sf PA$… that’s much stronger than just using the fact that it’s consistent.

@spaceisdarkgreen I think what I am confused about including the conditions that we can pre-suppose.  So may I please confirm that: the fact that "$\Bbb N$ is the standard model of PA" does not come for free. In particular, we assume PA is consistent so it has a model. Is that correct? But you seem to also claim "$\Bbb N$ is a model of PA" is stronger than "PA is consistent". If we are given that PA is consistent, what is the barrier of getting "$\Bbb N$ is a model of PA" form there?

And yes, I am aware that what I used is just soundness. But now my main confusion might be I have presupposed too many things.

@Y.X. soundness (in the sense of arithmetical soundness, not the easy direction of the completeness theorem… I meant the former in my comment, you may have meant the latter in yours) is stronger than consistency. If PA has any model (regardless if $\mathbb N$ is a model), then it’s consistent.

@Y.X. now, it’s a bit odd to not assume PA is sound (hence consistent) unless we have a very conservative foundation of math (e.g. it’s provable in ZFC or a lot less that PA is sound). So I find it more comfortable to state the theorem in terms of any computably axiomatizable consistent (or $\omega$-consistent, or sound) extension of Robinson arithmetic, which is also more general.

@spaceisdarkgreen I see. So, if I am just proving the claim that "there exists some facts on $\Bbb N$ which PA does not prove" in the ambient context of "the standard model of ZF", then we do have $\Bbb N\vDash PA$, so we do not need to assume in addition that "PA is $\omega$-consistent". Is that correct? If no, where is the error again?

It seems then, it might be worthwhile to point out the fact (of course, if it is true...) that "when using PA to argue about the incompleteness of a theory, the theory does not need to contain a model of PA, and this is why $\omega$-consistency is required". Is that true?

@Y.X. Correct... no error. The argument for (this direction of) the weak form of GIT for a sound theory $T$ is just "if $T$ proves $\lnot \Delta$ then by definition of $\Delta,$ $T$ proves that $T$ proves $\Delta$, but since $T$ is sound that means $T$ must really prove $\Delta$, but then $T$ is inconsistent, which contradicts the assumption that it is sound." (Which is very similar to your argument.) Note, the weaker assumption of $\omega$-consistency is also suboptimal, and it in fact holds for merely consistent theories (with the other usual assumptions), though the argument is a bit harder

@Y.X. To your second question, as I said in the last comment, $\omega$-consistency is not required, it is just required for showing the standard Godel sentence to not be refutable in that (suboptimal) proof.  I can't tell what you mean by your reasoning exactly. I would say that because it's quite possible for a generic consistent theory $T$ to prove its own inconsistency (e.g. consider $T :=\sf PA + \lnot \sf Con_{\sf PA}$), hence $\forall x \mathsf{Prv}_T(x),$ hence $\lnot \Delta_T$, we certainly need an assumption other than mere consistency (again, just for this proof).

As mentioned in the comments, the issue is that when you assume $\mathbb N\models \sf PA,$ you are assuming full soundness of $\sf PA.$ This is stronger than assuming $\omega$-consistency, which is equivalent to $\Sigma_1$-soundness.
As a note, $\omega$-consistency is not a necessary assumption for the first incompleteness theorem: Rosser proved consistency suffices (along with the other usual assumptions of computable axiomatizability and interpreting a sufficient amount of arithmetic). But it is necessary to conclude the Gödel sentence is undecidable in the system: for instance, $\sf PA + \lnot Con(PA)$ is consistent (provided $\sf PA$ is), but it refutes its Gödel sentence.
